# Android Java math logic issue

Tags: java, android

I want to message the player if he score a specific score.

What I am currently using ..

```
if(score <= 4){
 messagePlayer("You scored 1.");

} else if(score <= 19){
 messagePlayer("You scored 1.");
 messagePlayer("You scored 5.");

} else if(score <= 49){
 messagePlayer("You scored 1.");
 messagePlayer("You scored 5.");
 messagePlayer("You scored 20.");

} else if(score <= 99){
 messagePlayer("You scored 1.");
 messagePlayer("You scored 5.");
 messagePlayer("You scored 20.");
 messagePlayer("You scored 50.");

} else if(score >= 100){
 messagePlayer("You scored 1.");
 messagePlayer("You scored 5.");
 messagePlayer("You scored 20.");
 messagePlayer("You scored 50.");
 messagePlayer("You scored 100.");
}
```

The scores I want are:

> - 1 Point
> - 5
> - 20
> - 50
> - 100

**Is my logic 100% right and accurate?** I think my first one `score <= 4` is **wrong**, so if he gets `0` he can also get the message `You scored 1`. And I am **not** using `score == x,` because I need to message the player at the end, when he finish, so his highscore like 15.

Comment: What about doing some JUnit test?

Comment: I cannot do a lot of tests, cuz the messagePlayer method only message the player once then saves that he got messaged in a preference, then it will be ignored if he scores the same next time, that is why he can get messaged for both scores ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicitly exclude zero like this:

```
if(score > 0 && score <= 4){
 messagePlayer("You scored 1.");

}
```

Or better yet, store your boundary values in an array and solve the problem in one loop:

```
int[] boundaries = { 1, 5, 20, 50, 100 };

for (int i : boundaries) {
    if (score >= i) {
        messagePlayer("You scored " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: thats for 1, so I can use the same for other? like if(score > 4 && score <= 19){ for 5 .. and if(score > 19 && score <= 49){ for 20 .. etc? will work fine?

Answer (score 1):

The program as it exists now will always tell the user they scored 1, as long as they scored at least one, because your if-else will never make it past the first if, which will evaluate to true.

Better usage really would be to loop through your target scores an message each as the user crossed that threshold:

```
int[] targets = {0,1,5,20,50,100}

for (int i : targets) {
 if (score >= i) {
  messagePlayer("You scored " + i + ".")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make this code much more readable:

```
if(score <= 4)
    messagePlayer("You scored 1.");
if(score <= 19)
    messagePlayer("You scored 5.");
if(score <= 49)
    messagePlayer("You scored 20.");
if(score <= 99)
    messagePlayer("You scored 50.");
if(score >= 100)
    messagePlayer("You scored 100.");
```

Comment: That's not more readable, infact that coding style is deemed bad coding practice by many, and allows for easy mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to also check in your first if statement for higher than zero result.You could alter your first if statement like this

```
if(score>0 && score <= 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

i will modify little bit your structure

```
if( score >0){
 messagePlayer("You scored 1.");
} 
if(score >4){
 messagePlayer("You scored 5.");

} 
if(score > 19){
 messagePlayer("You scored 20.");

}

if(score > 49){
 messagePlayer("You scored 50.");

} 
if(score > 99){
 messagePlayer("You scored 100.");
}
```

note that, i removed `else` statements

Comment: but if I score 75 .. wouldn't it be confused to go to if(score > 19){
 or if(score > 49){ or if(score >4){ or if(score >0){ ?

Comment: @JohnJared it will satisfy all conditions and will display all messages, same like you had before